# json decode undefined index

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am calling a function save and in this function i am sending a $.post into 'upp.php':

```
function save(){

var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

var newItem = {};
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

newItem[num] = {
    "methv": document.getElementById("methv").value
    ,'q1': document.getElementById("q1").value,
    'q2':document.getElementById("q2").value,
    'q3':document.getElementById("q3").value,
    'q4':document.getElementById("q4").value,
    'comm':document.getElementById("comm").value
};
oldItems.push(newItem);
localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));}

$.post('upp.php',{ items: JSON.stringify(oldItems) }, function(response) {
```

in upp.php i am using:

```
<?php 
$array = json_decode($_POST['items'], True);
foreach ($array as $key=>$line) {

}
?>
```

but i am gettin an undefined index for 'items'

EDIT:

what i get after posting response

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" media="all">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"/>
<script src="alan.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Data Collection</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--Wrapper-->
<div id="wrap">

<!--Header-->
<div id="header">
<h1> Data Collection </h1>
</div>



<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="homepage.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="comment.php">Comments</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>

    </ul>
</div><input type="text" id="data"/>


<div id="heading">
<h3> Welcome, alan </h3>
</div>
array(1) {
  ["items"]=>
  string(167) "[{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}},{"1173627548":{"methv":"dont know","q1":"-","q2":"-","q3":"U","q4":"-","comm":""}}]"
}


<div id="footer">
<h1> Footer </h1>
</div>

</div> <!--End of wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

yeah i get all this but the information is in there but it is also displaying other information

Comment: and putting __var_dump($_POST);__ in upp.php outputs what?

Comment: comes out with array(0){}

Comment: So your post is empty. Look at what @Quentin says about redirecting. You should look at the __response__ from your $.post

Comment: ive already taken the redirecting bit out of it. how do i do that?

Comment: Sorry but im just really confused atm and i have no idea what to do

Comment: put in alert(response); where your redirect was, to see the result of your post, which should contain the info your looking for (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ for how $.post works)

Comment: i get this: see Edited bit of question

Comment: so there is more in upp.php than what you've shown!! such as include("header.php"); ##code## include("footer.php");

Comment: sorry i didnt think that it was important because it doesnt affect the code does it?

Comment: yes it is important. Whatever is in upp.php will be in your response. You could always load the contents into the current page http://api.jquery.com/load/ or just submit (post) the form to upp.php

Answer (score 3):

After your Ajax request is successful you `window.location.href = "upp.php";` which makes a GET request to the same URL.

Since it is a GET request, `$_POST` is empty, so the error should be expected.

Test to see if `$_POST['items']` is an array key and branch your code for the two states.

Comment: oh i see, sorry i am new to javascript how could i test this|?

Comment: I still get an undefined Index

Comment: Sorry but im just really confused atm and i have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you are converting to JSON to do a post? Why not just serialize the form and post using jQuery, then you have the object available in PHP without any extra work..

**html...**

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input name="q1"></input>
   <input name="q2"></input>
   ...
</form>
```

****js...****

```
var formdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'upp.php',
   data:formData,
   success:function(){ /* ... */ }
});
```

php...

```
echo $_POST['q1'];
echo $_POST['q2'];
```

Comment: but it will have multiple values in the localStorage array? any ideas how to run a loop to fix that?